# Operator overload function not inside braces {}

Tags: kotlin

I'm completing the [Kotlin Koans Operators Overloading](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Operators%20overloading/Task.kt) exercise and the answer includes a class like so:

```
class RepeatedTimeInterval(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val number: Int)
operator fun TimeInterval.times(number: Int) = RepeatedTimeInterval(this, number)
```

I'm a bit confused why the `operator` function is not in side curly braces `{}`.

In all tutorials I've seen ([example](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operator-overloading)) the operator is always inside curly braces:

```
class Point(val x: Int = 0, val y: Int = 10) {

    // overloading plus function
    operator fun plus(p: Point) : Point {
        return Point(x + p.x, y + p.y)
    }
}
```

In fact I've never really seen any function of this syntax where there is no symbol between the class constructor and the following function.

Comment: This operator function is created as an extension function on TimeInterval, so there is no need for it to be u curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

The function you see there isn't a class method; it's not defined within the class, and doesn't form part of the class.  (It could even be defined in another file or another package entirely.)

Instead, it's an [**extension function**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html): a stand-alone function that's not part of the class, but behaves in a few respects as if it were.

You can tell because the function name has a `.` in it.  This tells the compiler that the function is *extending* the class before the `.`.

If the extension function is in scope, you can call it using the same syntax you use for calling methods; and within the function, `this` refers to an instance of the class (the ‘receiver’).  However, you can't access private methods or properties of the class; `this` could be null if it's extending a nullable type; and the function is resolved statically (at compile-time, like function calls; not at run-time, like method calls).

This is one of Kotlin's important features, so it's worth reading up on them.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are overloading the operator by providing an [Extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions). In Kotlin, you can appear to add functions to any existing class. Under the covers, this works like a static method in Java.

Both of these examples are overloading the plus operator on your `Point` class:

```
class Point(val x: Int = 0, val y: Int = 10) {

    operator fun plus(p: Point) : Point {
        return Point(x + p.x, y + p.y)
    }
}
```

Or using an extension function:

```
class Point(val x: Int = 0, val y: Int = 10)
operator fun Point.plus(p: Point) : Point {
    return Point(x + p.x, y + p.y)
}
```

These both look the same when you call them:

```
val p = Point(1, 2)
val x = p + p // x = 2, 4
```